# When an input button field is added to the page using jQuery, how to access values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have generated input button fields based on values inputted elsewhere in the page

```
 $('#saved_answers').prepend('<input type="button" name="remove_answer" value="' + answerstring + '"><br />');
```

Afterwards, I tried calling:

```
$("input:button[name=remove_answer]").click(function() {
  alert("Test!");
});
```

But nothing happens. When I view source, I also notice that none of the new code shows up. However, it does show up visually in the window.

Comment: Can you give it an id?

Comment: You won't find it on the source code because it's the original response from the server. However, you'll find it using a developer bar. I've used your code to add a button to this page (stack overflow itself) and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the jQuery on method rather than click, so something like

```
    $('#saved_answers').on('click', 'some selector for your newly added button', function(){
        alert("Test!");
    }
```

This will allow for the event to be attached correctly.

See [jQuery .on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

---

If you use this it should work:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="saved_answers"></div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
    $('#saved_answers').prepend('<input type="button" name="remove_answer" value="test" />');
    $('#saved_answers').on('click', 'input:button[name=remove_answer]', function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works. But I want to access the value of the specific button i clicked.

Comment: I tried replacing #saved_answers with input:button[name=remove_answer] but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to use #saved_answers as that is the container you are adding the new button to. To get the value of the button out you should be able to find it by using $(this).val()

Comment: I tried using $("input:button[name=remove_answer]").val() instead, and it only retrieves the first clicked value. Any other different clicks, I get the first clicked value returned

Comment: So what error do you get when you try that? Or what do you see in the dev tools if you try it?

Comment: You will get that if you have items with the same name on the page.

Comment: This works for me: `$('#saved_answers').on('click', function(){
      $('input:button[name=remove_answer]').on('click', function(){
        alert(this.value);
      });
    });` , the issue is: I have to double click for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I misunderstood your question. What you did is binding an event handler to the `click` event,

```
$("input:button[name=remove_answer]").click(function () {
    alert("Test!");
});
```

if you want to trigger the click event, you need this

```
$("input:button[name=remove_answer]").click();
```

Comment: But what if I want to do something with the value of the button afterwards?